Selecting multiple textviews with only one longclick
I am creating textviews on top of a imageview . I am detecting the text on the image and creating textviews with same position and sizes it works well but there is a problem
ı can only select the text of one textview when ı longclick on the textview .Once ı longclick ı want to be able select all of the textviews is that possible ?
this is my adapter code as you can see ı am creating textviews with the same position and sizes with word boxes that is created by orc so basiclly every word can be selected but ı cant drag the selector to select all sentence
private static List<Bitmap> pdfBitmaps;
public static androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView textView;
public static  boolean iscopying = false ;



public PdfAdapter(List<Bitmap> pdfBitmaps) {
    this.pdfBitmaps = pdfBitmaps;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pdf_page_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
    Bitmap bitmap = pdfBitmaps.get(position);

    holder.imageView.setBitmap(bitmap);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    // Clear previous TextViews
    holder.textContainer.removeAllViews();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
    public void run() {


            // Add new TextViews
            List<String> textValues = MainActivity.allPageTextValuesfordisplay.get(position);
            List<Rect> boundingBoxes = MainActivity.allPageBoundingBoxesfordisplay.get(position);
            List<Float> textSizes = MainActivity.allPageTextSizesfordisplay.get(position);

         for (int i = 0; i < textValues.size(); i++) {
                String text = textValues.get(i);
                Rect box = boundingBoxes.get(i);
                float textSize = textSizes.get(i);
                Log.d("sizefortext",""+textSize);


            textView = new androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView(holder.itemView.getContext());
            textView.setTypeface(MainActivity.font);
            textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
            textView.setSingleLine(true);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.RED); // Set text color to transparent
            textView.setTextSize(8);
            textView.setText(text);

          //  textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 50, 1, 0)); // Optional: background to visualize the bounding box

            // Set position and size based on bounding box
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    box.width(),
                    box.height()
            );
             params.leftMargin = box.left;
             params.topMargin = box.top+5;


            textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    
            holder.textContainer.addView(textView);

            Log.d("textview eklendi","yeni bir textview eklendi");




            }
        }
    }, 10000);


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return pdfBitmaps.size();
}


public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CustomImageView imageView;
    FrameLayout textContainer;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_page_image);
        textContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container_layout);

    }



}


Can you show some code?

ı edited the question with code this is my adapter code to create the ımageviews as you can see ı am creating the textviews on top of the imageview and it works perfectly but ı just can select one word at a time because they are all different textviews

Can you give more information about the intent of selecting the TextViews? For example, would you like to be able to copy all of the text to the clipboard?

I am trying to create a pdf editor app and i want to be able to select and copy the text on the page like a regular pdf app
